# How to disappear the loader in angular

Tags: html, angular

When my observables is completed, i want to disappear the loader and replace by an icon.

My back code ( angular )

```
 this.displayCancel = false;
this.autoUnsubscribe(this.ranchService.currentRanch$.subscribe(ranch => (this.ranch = ranch)));
this.autoUnsubscribe(this.ranchService.ranches$.subscribe(ranches => {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:align invalid-void
  this.ranches = ranches; }, (error: void) => (error), () => {
  this.displayCancel = true;
}));
```

displaycancel is for the icon i want to replace after the loader

my html code :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!displayCancel">
        <mat-spinner [diameter]="14"></mat-spinner>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="displayCancel">
          <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
        </ng-container>
```

So the loader is displayed, but i want when my variable this.displayCancel = true, display the cancel button. But nothing happened

would love to receive some help 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
this.displayCancel = false;
this.autoUnsubscribe(this.ranchService.currentRanch$.subscribe(ranch => (this.ranch = ranch)));
this.autoUnsubscribe(this.ranchService.ranches$.subscribe(ranches => {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:align invalid-void
  this.ranches = ranches;
this.displayCancel = true;
 }, (error: void) => (error), () => {
  this.displayCancel = true;
}));
```

There error is unreachable may be try using it in the promise part and check.   And check whether by default the true and false of the displayCancel is working of working then add the line

```
this.displayCancel = true
```

in the success of the service